Custom RP2040 board not working
I have designed a custom RP2040 board referring to the official hardware design guide for RP2040.
When I boot the device in bootsel mode, it does get detected as a USB mass storage device on my host machine i.e. it does get enumerated as a full speed device. But when I boot the device without grounding the bootsel pin, the device does not get enumerated on my host machine and shows the following error -:  Device notresponding to setup address. Device not accepting address 126, error -71
I was able to drag drop the micropython firmware uf2 file when the device is connected as mass storage device and the device rebooted on successful pasting of the uf2 file, but the device could not get enumerated on reboot.
I tried to verify the working of flash by flashing a file onto the device and reading it back using the picotool, it works fine.
I even tried to run the application code (pico sdk) directly from the RAM using picotool, but no luck there as well.
What I could conclude was:

The device is working in USB device mode probably indicating there is no fatal error in USB hardware.
The flash chip is working fine and probably the device is able to
communicate with it as well.
The device is crashing/not working when it gets to executing the
application code in the flash boot mode (bootsel pin high). The ground pad connection under the RP2040 chip is not ideal.

I would like to have opinions/guidance on what could be the issue.
Criticism on the PCBdesign is also welcome :)
Attaching relevant parts of schematic and PCB files for reference, lmk for any more details.



If your uploaded firmware is supposed to do something with USB, what would it be? Or should it do nothing?

Designing a 2-layer board for MCUs is actually much harder than 2 layers. Novices should choose 4 layers always, since it will at least have a chance of working. Go with a 4-layer board. You have very high impedance power and ground distribution. 4 later layout will fix it with some precautions obviously. A 2-layer layout is possible but hard. If you share your design files (ideally on github), I can redo the layout to show how it should be done.

@Justme A MicroPython firmware for RP2040 has built-in USB support and should enumerate without issues. The layout is unsalvageable. It has no chance of working properly.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica So it should enumerate but as what? Mass storage, HID keyboard, CDC ACM, or something else?

@Justme I don’t recall, I think it should be CDC ACM.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica - Hi, In your comment above which says: "Designing a 2-layer board for MCUs is actually much harder than 2 layers" I'm fairly sure you mean "Designing a 2-layer board for MCUs is actually much harder than 4 layers" - yes? (That has certainly been my experience for non-trivial complexity PCBs, especially if space-constrained) If so, and with your agreement, I'll edit that typo and change it from "2" to "4", to avoid the comment being confusing for future readers. Please let me know. TY (Also "4 later" should be "4 layer" - yes?)

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica - Thank you for your respone.
PCB_files I have uploaded the pcb design files here, it would be really great if you could point out my mistakes in the design, so that i can improve on those.
Thanks!
